# Apache PdfBox verision 2.0.27 Not able to import PDImageXObject

Tags: java, pdfbox

[image]I'm trying to import one pdfbox package but Not able to import it.

```
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.PDImageXObject;
```

[image]

Comment: IDE (Eclipse or IDEA) ? Project Type ? Maven or Gradle ? or no Maven or Gradle ? add jar file into IDE project (IDEA , `Project Settings` -> `Libraries` -> `+` add jar file)

Comment: @life888888 attached screenshot, can you please check once

Comment: @life888888 pdfbox jar file is already added.

Comment: May I ask why `org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics` appears under `Source Packages`?

Comment: @life888888 Okay, I removed from source packages, Now I'm not getting errors. Thank you

Comment: Somebody please put this as an answer